# Cannot render the template since it's false, null or undefined

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js, marionette

I am working on template system using backbone.marionette.js.
Here is my code.

index.html

```
<div data-role="header" class="header">

</div> 
<div id="main" class="p-relative">  
    <aside id="sidebar" class="sidebar">

    </aside>

    <section id="content" class="main container">

    </section>
</div>

<div data-role="footer" class="footer">

</div>
```

default.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'backbone', 
    'marionette',
    'Test'
    'text!templates/home/default.html'
  ],
function(
    $,
    Backbone,
    Marionette,
    Test,
    DefaultPageTemplate
){
var MainRegion = Backbone.Marionette.Region.extend({
    el: '.main'
});

var Test = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

Test.addInitializer(function(options){
    /* create a new layout for Default Page */
    var defaultLanding = new LayoutDefaultPage();
    Test.defaultRegion.show(defaultLanding);
});
var LayoutDefaultPage = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
    template: DefaultPageTemplate
});

Test.addRegions({
    defaultRegion: MainRegion,
});

return Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({    
    templateHelpers: ModelHelper    
}); 

Test.start();
});
```

When I execute above code, I am getting "Cannot render the template since it's false, null or undefined." Please help me out.

Comment: Maybe because you have undefined variable `layoutDefault` here         `Test.defaultRegion.show(layoutDefault);` and need to use `defaultLanding` instead ?

Comment: Sorry Eugene Glova, It is mine spelling mistake. Corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Your template is plain text. Try wrapping it in the underscore template function

```
_.template(DefaultPageTemplate)
```

Or require the file with handlebars

```
'hbs!templates/home/default'
```